# Alignment of checkbox in table columns

Tags: html, css

I have a problem that my checkboxes distance from the top is increasing in every column; how can I make them start from the top?

[image: example rendering]

Comment: By default content in table cell `<td>` is vertically centered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not your checkboxes that causes the problem. if you place a `vertical-align: top` style on your `td` style it will be fixed.

```
.checkboxCol {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

in your case this applies to your class `checkboxCol`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `vertical-align` to `top` for td

So for example add a class .vtop

```
.vtop {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

and then add the vtop class to the td that should have it, i.e.:

```
<td class="checkboxCol vtop">
```

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/dntnaL6o/

by the way: it is `<br>` not `</br>`

Answer (score 0):

Add style  set vertical-align:top .